# Prove $7^{2n}-1$ is divisible by 48

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, integers

Trying to prove $7^{2n}-1$ is divisible by 48.

I began by taking the base case $n=1$ so $7^{2}-1=48$ which is true.

Now from here taking the inductive step to get

$7^{2(n+1)}-1=48k$

$7^{2n+2}-1=48k$

$7^{2}*7^{2n}-1=48k$

Not quite sure where to go from here. Thanks.

Comment: $7^{2n}=(7^2)^n=(49)^n=(48+1)^n$; use binomial theorem and conclude.

Comment: If you're supposed to use induction, note that $7^{2(n+1)}-1=49\times 7^{2n}-1$ and use the inductive hypothesis that $7^{2n}-1$ is divisible by $48$, ie, $7^{2n}=48k+1$ for some integer $k$

Comment: Yeah I get that, just not quite sure how to conclude the proof

Comment: You show the base case, then assume the hypothesis for $n$ and show that it implies the statement for $n+1$, ie, $48\mid 7^{2n}-1\implies 48\mid 7^{2(n+1)}-1$; to show this (ie, prove the inductive step), use the argument given in the previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

First, it is bad practice to write the proofs in this way, beginning with what you want to show and rewriting until you get a true statement. This is very simply backwards: a proof should always go *from* what we know (or have assumed) *to* our desired conclusion.

So, your inductive step would be much better written as a string of equalities, i.e.

$$7^{2(n+1)} - 1 = 7^{2n+2} - 1 = 7^2 * 7^{2n} - 1 = \text{...[fill this in]}.$$

Beyond this, your inductive step should always begin by stating your inductive hypothesis! So overall, your inductive step should look like:

> Suppose that, for some positive integer $n$, there is an integer $k$ such that $7^{2n} - 1 = 48k$. Then
> $$7^{2(n+1)} - 1 = 7^{2n+2} - 1 = 7^2 * 7^{2n} - 1 = \text{...[fill this in]}.$$

Now it's a little more clear what to do: apply the inductive hypothesis to rewrite $7^{2n}$ as $48k+1$! Hope this helps.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, this is indeed bad practice if one doesn't really know what one's doing. But when that's not the case, this "going backwards" technique can actually be pretty useful, like in epsilon-delta proofs.

Comment: Yes, I agree! Or at least, "going backwards" is a very useful technique for figuring out how a proof should work on your own scratch paper. But it should not appear in a "finished product" formal proof, except perhaps in contexts where the audience is both aware that a translation from backwards to forwards is necessary and able to perform that translation on the fly. Anyway, this answer is aimed at those (like presumably OP) who are new to formal proofs and still learning the ropes :)

Comment: I completely agree!

Answer (score 1):

Let S = $1 + 49 + 49^2 + \cdots + 49^{n-1} $

\begin{align}
        S &= 1 + 49 + 49^2 + \cdots + 49^{n-1} + 49^n - 49^n\\
        S &= 1 + 49(1 + 49 + 49^2 + \cdots + 49^{n-1}) - 49^n \\
        S &= 1 + 49S - 49^n \\
 49^n - 1 &= 48S\\
       48 &\mid 49^n - 1 \\
       48 &\mid 7^{2n} - 1 \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You can use

$7^{2n}-1=(1+48)^n-1$

Using binomial theorem

$7^{2n}-1= 1+48n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}48^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} 48^3+....+ \frac{n!}{n!}48^n -1$

from here you can see

$48|(7^{2n}-1)$

Answer (score 0):

It does not need induction. Just see that
$$7^{2n} = 49^n \equiv 1^n = 1\mod 48$$
and therefore $$48 \mid 7^{2n}-1.$$

But, if you really want an inductive proof, let $a_n=7^{2n}-1$.

$a_1=48$ and then $48\mid a_1$. Notice that
$$a_{n+1} = 7^{2n+2}-1 = 49\cdot 7^{2n}-1 = 49 (7^{2n}-1) + 48 = 49 a_n + 48.$$
Suppose that $48\mid a_n$, that is, $a_n= 48k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$a_{n+1} = 49 a_n + 48 = 49 \cdot 48 k + 48 = 48 (49k+1) $$
and therefore $48\mid a_{n+1}$. The results follows by the principle of Induction.